# rewrite origin history with upstream history?

Tags: git

I'm working on a large team, and the team regularly squashes commits to the upstream. At this point, my origin's history is different enough from upstreams, that the only way to "sync" them up anymore, is to reset to upstream and force push to origin.

Is there a way to "sync" or rewrite my origin's history with upstreams, to get rid of the "mini" commits on mine, and replace them with the squashed ones from upstream?

Comment: It sounds like you need git rebase. Personally use [git up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) to pull down all branches every morning, then rebase my development branches onto master. Before merging into master and after code review I'd squash all commits on my branch before pushing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this in git - I'll try and explain one of them. Let's suppose you're working on a local branch named `bug_fix`. You should be able to get back in sync with upstream by doing the following:

1. Create a new branch off `bug_fix`:

   ```
   git checkout -b temp_bug_fix
   ```
2. Get back to the original `bug_fix` branch and reset `HEAD` to a point where your local branch was in sync with upstream. Assuming that's 10 commits ago, the commands would be:

   ```
   git checkout bug_fix
   git reset --hard HEAD~10
   ```
3. Pull all the new changes from upstream. This will sync `bug_fix` with `origin`

   ```
   git pull origin <upstream_branch>
   ```
4. Cherry-pick your commits from the `temp_bug_fix` branch using the appropriate SHAs

   ```
   git cherry-pick <you_commit_SHA>
   ```
5. Now that you're in sync, you can push to upstream normally (without using `-f`)

   ```
   git push origin <upstream_branch>
   ```

This answer makes the assumption that all your changes have been made after all the 'mini' commits made by others.

I'm curious to understand how your local branch got into this state in the first place. The standard practice is that developers should squash their commits *before* pushing to origin. Once a local branch has been merged upstream, no one should change the history using a force push - that's just a recipe for trouble.

Comment: I still had to do a force push to get the push to land, otherwise, it askes me to git pull before pushing again, because the tip of the current branch is behind the remote (even though i did a pull first). If I pull, I get a ton of merge conflicts, hundreds. Thats why I was asking if it was possible to just "reset"/start over on that branch, rewrite the history completely, so that doesnt happen in the future.

Comment: Ideally, there should have been no conflicts if you had followed the above steps.

If you're still having issues every time you push, you could delete your local branch(provided you’ve pushed all your local changes upstream already and have no local changes) and create a new local branch that tracks your origin branch. This will effectively help you 'reset'/start over.